# Algorithmic complexity converting CSR/CSC to BSR

Tags: algorithm, scipy, sparse-matrix, complexity-theory

I was wondering what is the algorithmic complexity of a conversion from `CSC (compressed sparse column)` or `CSR (compressed sparse row)` to `BSR (blocked sparse row)`?

Say I have

- a CSC `m x m`-matrix `A = csc(m,m)` with `n` non-zero elements
- a CSR `m x m`-matrix `B = csr(m,m)` with `n` non-zero elements

BSR format:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.html
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-sparse-blas-bsr-matrix-storage-format

Comment: First, I'm not sure that the `scipy.sparse.bsr` format uses `mkl`.  It looks like much of the `bsr` class code is in the `source` link of that `scipy` documentation (python code).  But it also looks like the core of the `csr` to `bsr` conversion is in C, with code in `https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.1/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h`.  Comments in that code say `Complexity: Linear`.

Comment: I just put `mkl' as another reference in understanding BSR. They Scipy and MKL implementations could be totally different. Thanks for the code reference, updated to [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4bfc152f6ee1ca48c73c06e27f7ef021d729f496/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L181)

Comment: Since BSR is very like CSR (it just uses vectors for dense sub-matrices within a row), BSR Is almost certainly linear time in the number of entries with constant space overhead.  CSC to BSR depends the internal algorithm, which I don't know. A commonsense implementation would also be linear time, but might need linear temp space. Anyway, it would be easy enough to gin up a benchmark that converts 100x100, 1000x1000, and 10000x10000 and maybe larger examples with various sparsity and see how it behaves.